# I want to retrieve 'paid' value from and it is in 2nd row 2nd column using selenium

Tags: selenium

Below is the table code:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Automation Tool</th>
      <th>Licensing</th> 
      <th>Market response</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Selenium</td>
      <td>Free</td>
      <td>In</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>QTP</td>
      <td>Paid</td>
      <td>Out</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='yourTableid']/tr[3]/td[2]")).getText();
```

Above code will fetch value from 2nd column of 2nd row of your table. You just need to know the table id. If you don't have table id, you need to find other table attribute to find the table first.

Edited to correct row. Thanks Sudharsan.

Comment: The above code will get the value `free` not `paid`. So it should be `//table[@id='yourTableid']/tr[3]/td[2]`